# When is it possible to bound a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\big|\ f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\ \big| \le {\prod}_{i=1}^n h_i(x_i)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Is there any result that specifies when a multivariate function   $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be bounded (either locally or globally) by a product of some functions $h_i:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$:

$\large\bigg|\ f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\ \bigg| \le {\prod}_{i=1}^n h_i(x_i)$